# Powershell: Show what groups are added to a set of folders?

Tags: powershell, permissions, active-directory, active-directory-group

I spent some time searching through similar questions on here to see if I could find some answers, but I'm so clueless about AD that I'm not even sure how to tell if I'd found what I was looking for...

I have a number of folders in one place. All these folders are similarly named:

```
Reports_January_2011  
Reports_March_2012  
Reports_March_2012
```

All of these folders have a pair of identically named subfolders:

```
Export
Raw
```

I need to see all groups that have any permissions configured in these folders. Basically I have a Reports folder for every month for the past 5 years, each of those with the two subfolders. I need to make sure they all have the right groups added to them.

I started trying to figure out the regex to pick out only the right reports folders, but I'm totally lost on where to start for the "Get groups" part of the script. My experience with PS is limited to batch renaming, moving, etc. Simple one line stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice PowerShell [module (File System Security PowerShell Module 1.3)](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85) that could make your life easier. With that module in place, you can use the Get-Ace cmdlet to list permissions for files using a command like the one below:

```
Get-Item F:\backup | Get-Ace | Where-Object { $_.ID -like "*users*" }
```

Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this this:

```
dir c:\ | ? { $_.psiscontainer } |`
Get-Acl  | fl -property @{n="Path";E={ convert-path $_.pspath}}, @{N="AccessList";`
E={ $_.AccessToString -split '\n' | ? { $_.startswith("MyDomain") }}; }
```

to have a list with path and access list. Removing the las pipe also local user are listed